# Traversing Java JDT AST and Building java tree

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt, json-simple

The default implementation of ASTVisitor traverses in a depth first manner. So one can get the source file in order of occurrence. My requirement is to build a java tree out of the ASTNode

I am motivated by the following

- [API to compare AST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474046/api-to-compare-ast)
- http://www.programcreek.com/2011/11/use-jdt-astparser-to-parse-java-file/
- [Eclipse Abstract Syntax Tree Diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974855/eclipse-abstract-syntax-tree-diff)

  ```
  public class AST_Json_Bulid_tree
  ```

  {

  ```
  static private List  sourcecodeStatObj = new LinkedList();  

  public static void parse(String str, final String path) 
  {
      ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8 );
      parser.setSource(str.toCharArray());
      parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT); 
      parser.setResolveBindings(true); // we need bindings later on
      final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

      try{
          cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() 
          {           

          public boolean visit(ForStatement node) 
          {               
              List<String> initializer = node.initializers();
              Expression exp = node.getExpression();
              String expression = "";
              List updater = node.updaters();             
              int length = node.getBody().getLength();                        
              int startposition = node.getStartPosition();


              int startLineNumber = cu.getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition());
              int nodeLength = node.getLength();                      
              int endLineNumber = cu.getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition() + nodeLength);

              boolean isexpNull = false ;

              forcount += 1;

              if(exp == null)
              {
                  isexpNull = true;
              }




              if(!isexpNull)
              {
                  this.names.add(exp.toString());
                  expression = exp.toString();                                
              }               

              Map forobj=new LinkedHashMap();
              forobj.put("Node_Type", "FOR_STATEMENT");
              forobj.put("keyword", "for");

              forobj.put("Initializers", initializer.toString());
              forobj.put("Expression", expression);
              forobj.put("Updater", updater.toString());  

              forobj.put("CF.BeginLine, CF.EndLine", "(" + startLineNumber + ", "  + endLineNumber + ")");

              String astjsonText = JSONValue.toJSONString(forobj);

              try 
                  {
                      sourcecodeStatObj.add(forobj);
                  } 

              catch (Exception e) 
                  {                       
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }

              //Accept the visit of the other parts
              //super.visit(node);
              if(!isexpNull)
              {                           
                  exp.accept(this);
              }

              for (Iterator it = node.initializers().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) 
              {
                  Expression e = (Expression) it.next();
                  e.accept(this);

              }


              for (Iterator it = node.updaters().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) 
              {
                  Expression e = (Expression) it.next();
                  e.accept(this);                         
              }

              node.getBody().accept(this);


              return false; // continue 
          }

          public boolean visit(WhileStatement node) 
          {
              // Similar code goes here
              return false; // don't continue to visit   
          }

          public boolean visit(DoStatement node) 
          {           
              // Similar code goes here                   
              return false; // don't continue to visit  
          }

          public boolean visit (IfStatement node) 
          {
              // Similar code goes here                                           
              return false; // don't continue to visit  
          }


          public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) 
          {                               
              // Similar code goes here                   
              return false;                       

          }               
          public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration node)
          {   
              // Similar code goes here                                       
              return true;
          }

           public boolean visit(AnnotationTypeDeclaration node) 
           {
              // Similar code goes here                                            
              return true;
           }


           public boolean visit(PackageDeclaration node) 
           {  
              // Similar code goes here                                        
              return false;
           }

           public boolean visit(EnumDeclaration node)
           {
              // Similar code goes here                                            
               return true;
          }

          @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
          public boolean visit(Block node)
          {
              // Similar code goes here                   
              return true;
          }

          public boolean visit(ImportDeclaration node)
          {
              // Similar code goes here                   
              return false;

          }

          //Other STATEMENTs goes here 

          });

              }

      finally
      {       
          writeJsonFile(path);                                
      }   
  }
  ```

  }

So here the sourcecodeStatObj contains all the items in order of visited i.e depth first search.

other class's and methods' constructs are omitted here.

I would appreciate if you give me the direction and the twist! 
Thank you!